# RS485 Pinout when using PyModbus

Tags: serial, rs232, pid-controller, rs485, db9

I am trying to control a RS-485 RTU device ([Love 16C-3](http://www.dwyer-inst.com/PDF_files/E_90_BPC.pdf)) using a Python script (`pymodbus` library) that runs on a Windows 10 PC. The hardware is connected to the computer using a [USB-RS232 cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QUZY4L0).

In my initial test, the Python script is not able to read anything off the RS-485 device.

1. What is the RS-485 pin out for the DB9 connector?
2. Should a [USB-RS485 cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CPLOVW) be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

RS-232 is RS-232, RS-485 is RS-485. They are mutually incompatible on the electrical layer, they use different voltages and signalling. You need a USB to RS-485 cable first.

There are no RS-485 signals (A and B) on a DB-9 in a USB to RS-232 cable.